# android set button with customerized color and round corner programmatically

Tags: android, button

I am now working on a drawing app, and users can select their customerized colors. 
Then the customerized color button would then be showing the chosen color. However, it become squared-corner once it was set to be the customerized color.

My coding is as follows:

### My question is :

1. How to set the `customBtn` such that it is round-corner and filled with customerized color (best to be programmatically as the customerized color will be changed upon user's choice)
2. actually what are those 10 for the new float[] array represent?

Many thanks!!

### Coding:

```
 customColorCode = Color.argb(alphaSeekBar.getProgress(), redSeekBar.getProgress(), 
         greenSeekBar.getProgress(), blueSeekBar.getProgress());         



 RoundRectShape rs = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10}, null, null);
 ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(rs);
 customBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);
 customBtn.setBackgroundColor(customColorCode);
```

Comment: I am having the same issue as above.Corners become square-shaped after setting the customized color but not otherwise.any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. change background color to set the different colors to button
2. public RoundRectShape (float[] outerRadii, RectF inset, float[] innerRadii) 
   Added in API level 1
   RoundRectShape constructor. Specifies an outer (round)rect and an optional inner (round)rect.

Parameters
outerRadii  An array of 8 radius values, for the outer roundrect. The first two floats are for the top-left corner (remaining pairs correspond clockwise). For no rounded corners on the outer rectangle, pass null. 
inset  A RectF that specifies the distance from the inner rect to each side of the outer rect. For no inner, pass null. 
innerRadii  An array of 8 radius values, for the inner roundrect. The first two floats are for the top-left corner (remaining pairs correspond clockwise). For no rounded corners on the inner rectangle, pass null. If inset parameter is null, this parameter is ignored.